# HTML Anchor and Input Button Font Difference

Tags: css-float

Anyone knows why the font of this elements are not the same?

Using Anchor Element

```
<a style="font-weight: bold; ">bold</a>
```

Using Input Button

```
<input type="submit" value="bold" 
style="font-weight:bold; border: none; background-color: transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `font-family` and `font-size` are different too:

see
   http://jsfiddle.net/RQBr3/

vs
http://jsfiddle.net/RQBr3/1/
with `font-size` and `font-family` added.